# Phpmyadmin Database Trigger Creation Query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

I have two tables **`inventory`** table(columns `'inventory_id','asset','item','delivered_by', 'received_by', 'quantity ''date'`) and a **`summary`** table ('stock_id', 'asset', 'item', 'qty'). I want to create a database trigger that sums up the quantity of assets and items from the **`inventory`** table into the **`summary`** table after insertion of a new row in the **`inventory`** table. .

An Instance:

[image: inventory table]

Expectation From trigger

[image: Summary Table]

Here is a query i tried to create the trigger but it failed

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateqty
AFTER INSERT ON inventory 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE INTO stock SET qty = (old.qty + stock.qty)
WHERE inventory.item = summary.item_name OR summary.asset_name
```

Any ideas as to how to create the trigger for my scenario would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did this syntax?

Comment: @P.Salmon the above syntax didn't. can you please help me out a query to create the trigger?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as update into, there is no such thing as old. in an insert trigger,the where clause is invalid but I cannot guess what it should be, every begin must have an end, every statement must have a terminator - usually ;. Are you attempting this in phpmyadmin, mysql workbench or something else?

Comment: i'm attempting this in phpmyadmin. The WHERE clause is supposed to check whether any of the quantity being inserted  from the inventory is an asset or item then adds is to the quantity in the summary table. @P.Salmon